# How to play music, when a long click button depressed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an imageButton I want to play a music when, after a long press on my button , I remove hand from the button, then it will play music ,until I press another button , to stop it,

Comment: apply setOnLongClickListener to the imagebutton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `onTouchListener` for this purpose:

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED : Play the music here
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: how this is going to catch long press?